# How is firebase blacklisting perfomed?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

The [Firebase Analytics Error Codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors), includes the following:

> 11    App Instance logs blacklisted event
>
> - Name of blacklisted event
> - Event is ignored. A `firebase_error` event is logged with a `firebase_error_value` parameter which indicates the blacklisted event name.
>
> 12    App Instance sets blacklisted user property.
>
> - Name of blacklisted user property.
> - The user property change is ignored. A `firebase_error` event is logged with a `firebase_error_value` parameter which indicates the blacklisted user property.

How do I blacklist an event or property? Is it possible to have a whitelist instead?